# Формы слова "внимать"

Tags: словоформы

Сегодня споткнулась на слове "внимать". У меня не получилось образовать от него другие формы.
Ну, ясно, что я - внимаю, он - внимает и т.д. А вот с повелительным наклонением уже вопрос: внимай или внемли?
А споткнулась я на форме, отвечающей на вопрос "что сделают?" Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть в этой ситуации?

Comment: А споткнулась я на форме, отвечающей на вопрос "что сделают?"=== ВНИМАТЬ -- гл. нсв. Корректный вопрос: "Что будут делать?"

Comment: будут внимать.

Внемли. Пов. накл. от внимать.

Comment: Вы совсем не чувствуете разницу между "что сделают" и "что будут делать"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видовая пара: внять - внимать.

Форму простого будущего времени (что сделают?) образуют только глаголы СВ, но у глагола "внять", согласно словарю, её нет.

ВНЯТЬ,  буд. и повел. нет; св.

Формы пов. накл и сложного будущего времени образует глагол НВ "внимать": внимай и (в поэтич. речи) внемли, будет внимать.

Answer (score 1):

> Ну, ясно, что я - внимаю, он -
> внимает...

Пов.: *внимай.*

Буд.: *будут внимать.*

Помимо этих форм, в стихах возм. *внЕмлю* и *внемлЮ, внЕмлет,  внемлИ* и *внЕмли.*

Comment: Повторяю еще раз: меня интересует форма ЧТО СДЕЛАЮТ, а не "что будут делать". Это БОЛЬШАЯ РАЗНИЦА.

Comment: Повторяю еще раз: меня интересует форма ЧТО СДЕЛАЮТ, а не "что будут делать". Это БОЛЬШАЯ РАЗНИЦА.=== К моему сожалению, парный глаголу ВНИМАТЬ гл. сов. вида ВНЯТЬ имеет неполную парадигму. Употребляется только в прошедшем времени: ВНЯЛ.  В будущем времени не употребляется.

Comment: Как вариант: попробуйте использовать в будущем времени какой-либо из синонимов глаголов "внимать/внять". "Что сделают?" -- вслушаются,  прислушаются, выслушают с вниманием...